# Check if array element exists

Tags: javascript

The `startGameOfLife()` generates an array of 0s and 1s e.g. `[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and stores into `temp_space` in each loop. I have pushed the generated array into `this.hash_game_space` if it doesn't already exist. But the condition `this.hash_game_space.indexOf(temp_space)` doesn't seem to be working. Is there any way to check if the array already exists in `hash_game_space`?

```
count = 0;
hash_game_space = []
while(1) {
    temp_space = this.startGameOfLife();  // generates array of 10 number (0s or 1s)        
    // checks if element exists in hash_game_space  
    if(this.hash_game_space.indexOf(temp_space) == -1 || count == 0) {
        this.hash_game_space.push(temp_space); // pushes into an array
        count++;
    } else {
        console.log(count);
        console.log('end');
        break;      
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're pushing new Arrays onto the `hash_game_space` Array, then `.indexOf()` will never find a match because Arrays are compared by identity. So unless `startGameOfLife()` is going to return the same Array object, `.indexOf()` will always be `-1`, even if the Array's values are identical.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I used .join() to match the array elements with the generated array. :)

Comment: This is how I got over the problem. I used `.join()` to concat the generated array and pushed it into `hash_game_space` as a string. `this.hash_game_space.push(temp_space.join());`

Comment: Yep, that should work as long as you know the Arrays will only have numbers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the array's indexOf() which will return -1 if not found. If found, it will return zero or greater integer which is the index in the array.